# Ember-data error: "Assertion Failed: You need to pass a model name to the store's modelFor method"

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm getting this error when trying to consume the json from the backend.
I'm using Ember CLI version 2.5.0 and the RestAdapter.

Here's my routes/products/index.js looks like:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
   [...]
  },
  model: function() {
    return this.store.findAll('product');
  }
});
```

And here's what my json looks like:

```
{
   "products":[
      {
         "id":9,
         "name":"Product A",
         "price_cents":1500,
         "margin_cents":0,
         "commission":0,
         "expiration":null,
         "track_stock":false,
         "stock_amount":5,
         "brand":{
            "id":2,
            "name":"SuperPet"
         },
         "group":{
            "id":1,
            "name":"Group A"
         }
      },
      {
         "id":8,
         "name":"Product B",
         "price_cents":1500,
         "margin_cents":0,
         "commission":0,
         "expiration":null,
         "track_stock":false,
         "stock_amount":5,
         "brand":{
            "id":1,
            "name":"Whiskas"
         },
         "group":{
            "id":1,
            "name":"Group B"
         }
      }
   ],
   "meta":{
      "pagination":{
         "per_page":null,
         "total_pages":4,
         "total_objects":10
      }
   }
}
```

And by request, here's the model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

const { attr, belongsTo } = DS;

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: attr('string'),
  priceCents: attr('number'),
  marginCents: attr('number'),
  comission: attr('number'),
  expiration: attr('date'),
  trackStock: attr('boolean'),
  stockAmount: attr('number'),

  brand: belongsTo('brand')

});
```

Comment: Can you post your model?

Comment: Can you post your adapter, serializer (if any) and stack trace from console, which line is error coming from?

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue. This worked for me:

```
//app/serializers/product.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin,{   
    attrs: {
       brand: { embedded: 'always' },
       group: { embedded: 'always'}
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for submitting this response, I ended up doing the same. Although I eventually made it work, I won't be marking any answers as correct due to lack of experience with the framework, plus I ended up replacing Ember for React for this project. (sigh!)

Comment: @JayJay It's safe to mark this as the answer. I have worked with Ember for a long time and I agree that this is correct.

Answer (score 3):

You have the  brand: belongsTo('brand')

but you forgot the  group: belongsTo('group')

also .. these two ( brand, group ) have to be declared as embedded with the DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin  in the product serializer if you are going to embed them this way

Comment: Thank you for submitting this response, I  did use it while trying to fix the problem. Although I eventually made it work, I won't be marking any answers as correct due to my lack of experience with the framework, plus I ended up replacing Ember for React for this project. (sigh!)